# Horizontal List view not working inside vertical ListWheelScrollView in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

Content is rendered perfectly if there is single item but as soon as we try to fit carousel as one of the child of `ListWheelScrollView`, it doesn't understand the horizontal swiping.

This code works if used normal list view with normal ScrollController()

My requirement is to show the nearest child of list if user scrolls in between position so using `FixedExtentScrollController`

Scroll Controller used is fixed one
`FixedExtentScrollController()`
with below
ListWheelScrollView

Scroll controller used

```
final ScrollController scrollController = FixedExtentScrollController();
```

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      child: ListWheelScrollView.useDelegate(
        itemExtent: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.87,
        perspective: 0.001,
        physics: const FixedExtentScrollPhysics(),
        controller: scrollController,
        childDelegate: ListWheelChildBuilderDelegate(
          childCount: data.length,
          builder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return iStreamWidget.render(data[index]);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Horizontal List View with controller

```
final ScrollController scrollController = FixedExtentScrollController();
```

```
Container(
      height: height * 0.88,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
        horizontal: 20.0,
        vertical: 35.0,
      ),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          _buildTitle(carouselPostModel.title, postModel.postFontType, context),
          Expanded(
            child: SizedBox(
              width: double.infinity,
              child: ListView.separated(
                  itemCount: descriptionList.length,
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  controller: scrollController,
                  physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return _buildCard(
                      imageUrls[index],
                      descriptionList[index],
                      postModel.postFontType,
                      context,
                    );
                  },
                  separatorBuilder: (index, context) {
                    return const SizedBox(
                      width: 10.0,
                    );
                  }),
            )
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Comment: can you try adding scrollcontroller to horizontal list as well?

Comment: I added a ScrollController() but it doesn't help

Comment: may be share the whole code for me to help further?

Comment: Added scroll controller in question